# IntelliSense: a value of type "IDeviceServer *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "IDeviceServer *"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I can't understand this error, really. Please help me with it. The code is :

```
m_pIServer = new IDeviceServer(this);
```

and declarations is :

```
class IDeviceServer : public IOPCServer
{
  public:
    IDeviceServer( LPUNKNOWN );
  ...

IDeviceServer       *m_pIServer;
```

What means : **a value of type "IDeviceServer *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "IDeviceServer *"** ? I can't understand it.

Comment: I'm going to suspect the root cause of the error is somewhat related to `m_pIServer`. That's a member of `IDeviceServer` but it also has type `IDeviceServer*` ?!

Comment: No, no, m_pIServer is member of DeviceServer, and IDeviceServer is friend of DeviceServer.Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually occurs when you have redefined the class in a generic class/method and pass in an object of the old class.